# GSCript: Find active row and paste formulas in columns M and N

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to have a formula pasted in a relative cell and then another formula pasted in the cell to the left of it. The problem is that I want the right and left cell to always be column M,N respectively.

However, I am unsure how to get the code to look for columns M and N of the active row.

Thank you

```
function UntitledMacro2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=sum(5+1)');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=sum(4-1)');
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the row number of the active cell first then activate the selection of the columns N and O and set the row number, this way column M will be always be filled with data column M left and N right, then paste your formulas.

Something like this:

```
function UntitledMacro2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
  var rowNumber = spreadsheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  Logger.log("Selcted row number: " + rowNumber);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSelection("N" + rowNumber + ":O" + rowNumber);  
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=sum(5+1)');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=sum(4-1)');
};
```

I hope this helps, Greetings.

Comment: Thank you Mario. It did help! One thing I wanted to state in case others stumble upon this page is that the b's in your ActiveSelection line should probably be replaced with rowNumber. Or at least that is what I did to get it to work.

Comment: That is correct, I updated it but forgot to change "b" thanks for notice that. I just updated the post. I am glad that helps you.